# How do I find out what font is used in this picture/text

Tags: fonts

Could anyone help me with identifying the bellow font?

[image]

Comment: This isn't a TeX question. You can find it easily using [WhatTheFont](http://new.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/). I found http://new.myfonts.com/fonts/tilde/cheltenhm/bold-condensed/ which seemed like a decent match

Comment: This is clearly off-topic, so I've closed it. As @Mikael says, WhatThefont is the place to sort this type of thing.

Comment: @Joseph: Should we have a one-answers-all question "How do I find out what font is used in this picture/text"? (Unless there already is one)